# Why doesn't IE8 display these transparent slideshows properly?

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-8, slideshow, jcycle

I have 2 transparent jCycle slideshows (different timeouts) one next to the other with absolute positioning like this...

[image]

The transparent images fade in and out properly in all the other browsers except IE. In IE8, they display correctly at the beginning, but when one starts to fade the other disappears and I see the background. Then the same thing happens to the other one and so on...

Here's [the code](http://test.sopranowebdesign.com/slideshows/) if you want to check it out.

Do you have any ideas why this happens? I've tried playing around with z-index but with no luck...

Comment: Are you using png with transparency ?

Comment: Perhaps you can post some relevant code so we can help you.

Comment: I get the same result with PNG or GIF.

Comment: I've edited my question to include a link to the code too. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding:

```
cleartypeNoBg: true
```

to the [cycle options](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/options.html).

Comment: Solved my problem! Thank you so much!! You have no idea how much this was bugging me.